# create R markdown table of content experience in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to create the table of content experience for a shiny app.

So perhaps a shiny app like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("plot", tabName = "plot"),
      menuItem("slider", tabName = "slider")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(
        tabName = "plot",
        fluidRow(
          box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
        ),
        fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput('longtext')),
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "slider",
            sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(input$slider)])})
  
  output$longtext <- renderText({paste0(rep('blah', 100), collapse = '\n')})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But behave more like it would running an R markdown with a table of content enable. Similar to the code below, where clicking on the section in the table of content takes to the relevant part in the main app.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

### section 1

`r paste0(rep('blah', 100), collapse = '<br/>')`

### section 2

section content
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a shiny document.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

### section 1
```{r, echo=FALSE}
sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)

renderText({paste0(rep('blah', 100), collapse = '\n')})
```

### section 2
```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPlot({hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(input$slider)])})
```
````

Comment: I think it would be best to either use Rmarkdown with `runtime: shiny` OR use the Shinydashboard package, not both together. The Rmarkdown would feel more like a dynamic document, while the shinydashboard is more of a webapp, both are great, I would suggest started with Rmarkdown and shiny, then move to the dashboard and see what works best

Comment: @DanielJachetta The only reason I used `shinydashboard` above is to show what I had in mind. Perhaps that wasn't necessary and the R markdown example was enough.